# "Cannot access android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner" in android studio 3.2

Tags: android-studio, viewmodel

I have recently upgraded my android studio to version 3.2, and since everywhere I try to access fragment/activity attributes from my ViewModel classes, I get this "Cannot access android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner" message:

[image: example of the error message]

It does not affect compilation, but this annoying message pops in a lot of class.

Any ideas?

PS: I have already tried "Invalidate caches and restart" several times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just got the same problem after update, this helped:
Add this line to your module’s build.gradle script:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
}
```

Found it here: [Adding Components to your Project](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components)

Comment: Maybe you should check the description for AndroidX, the link above. Also I found that the “implementation” for lifecycle.extensions is not required anymore after I have changed the ExoPlayer library reference to 2.8.4

Comment: Show your build.gradle script content.

Comment: It works for me but Can anyone explain why we need this dependencies.?I am not using android architectural component in my project. I have updated targetSdkversion 28.

Comment: I would also need an explanation for the question. I am also not using any architectural components in the project. Then, why do we need to add this dependency to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and I resolved this issue by updating android support libraries in build.gradle file.

I would recommend updating your android support libraries to 27.1.1 or newer. No need to add this :

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
```